# UITableView background showing in Interface Builder but in simulator

Tags: uitableview, background

does anyone know why, if I add an image UIImage as background, I can clearly see it behind my grouped table view in Interface Builder.
However when I launch the app, the background is not showing at all, both in simulator and device.

Apart from adding the image, I suppose I already did all the steps at TableView programmatic side:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a post I made, I found two possible solutions, one with UIViewController in place of UITableVIewController as discussed here:

[UITableView with fixed image background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693978/uitableview-with-fixed-image-background)

with a disadvantage of header and footer problem with grouped table.

The other solution, involves writing more code and could be the case only if you have a common table that you share within different views of the apps: basically is to have a UIViewController calling a UITableViewController and attach its subview to self.view.