# UITableView with fixed image background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, background

Sorry but I found no clear answer on that.
I have an iphone app with a tab bar and a UINavigationController in each tab.
The interface is built with Interface Builder, and in the first tab there is a UITableView.
I have prepared the xib with main view (A) containing a table (T) and an image (IMG) background behind (image as subview of main view).
Later I assigned UITableViewController as owner. This is where problems start.
In IB if I connect view to A I got a runtime error telling me that controller cannot find a table.
If I connect controller view to T everything works fine, except that IMG is not shown.

The only solution I found is to create a new xib holding A and IMG with a UIViewController as owner. Then create a xib holding T only and UITableViewController as owner, correctly connected to T.
Then in viewDidLoad of the UIViewController:

```
iptc = [[IPPlantsTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IPPlantsView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

iptc.navigator=self.navigationController; // <-- need this

[self.view addSubview:iptc.view];
```

And this works, except that the table view seems to not know anything about navigationController, therefore detail view mechanism is not working, unless I set a property for it in UITableViewController.
I also run in to some other problems, for example all the logic for adding/deleting/creating rows to table has to be handled in UIViewController and sent to UITableViewController.

Is there another way for having a fixed image in a table view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewController is a convenience class; you can equally just use UIViewController and implement the correct callbacks.

In OS 3.2+, you can just set UITableView.backgroundView. If IB doesn't let you do this, you can do it in code instead.

Alternatively, you might be able to wire up the `view` and `tableView` outlets differently, unless tableView just does `(UITableView*)self.view`.

Comment: Thanks... I have succesfully managed to convert UITableViewController to a normal UIViewController and magically the background appear. However I have a last annoying problem, the top and bottom cells I made with IB just show a black background below the rounded corner (like a .gif without transparency). If I declare a color for UITableView instead of clearColor, the problem disappear, but of course I cannot see the background.

Comment: What do I have to set for backgroundView ? Is it not enough to clearColor the table view ?

Comment: I switched to plain table rather than a grouped one, and built two ui custom cells more, one for the header and one for the footer. So the problem is temporaly solved.

Answer (score 2):

Mmmm

I will be honest i HATE Interface Builder ;-) so I can't help you about this.

But to set a fixed image in the background of a UITableView you should :
- set background color of the UITableView to [ UIColor clearColor ] (and maybe the background of the cell too)
- set and uiimageview below the uitableview view that contains the image :)

In that way this should work.

But without xcode project I can't help you more ^^

Good luck

Comment: YEAH ! all against IB xD I totally agree

Comment: Altough there are time when is necessary and faster to create view programmatically, I rather prefer to create template with IB. There's much control on element positioning, graphic, ecc...